# Fail to log the output of commands in crontab to a text file

Tags: linux, cron, ping

The crontab (user's crontab) configure is like this:

```
@reboot ping 1.1.1.1>/home/username/test.log
```

After rebooting, the file "test.log" was generated, however it's only an empty file.
and `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` shows that the `ping` command was executed.
any one know what the problem is?

I tried some of the solutions that I googled, such as changing `ping` to `/bin/ping` or setting the `HOME` environment variable, however still not working.

Comment: Probably the network is not yet available at the time `cron` runs this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to reproduce your problem:

```
ping host.invalid > file.txt
```

`ping` will run and show an error, and `file.txt` will be created but empty.
This is because Unix programs differentiate between output and errors, and you're only redirecting the output.

To redirect the errors as well, you can use:

```
@reboot ping 1.1.1.1 > /home/username/test.log 2>&1
```